# Differences between FC-RX600-11 and FC-RX600-10?

Tags: shimano, crankset, compatibility, chainring, grx

Is there any **documented** difference between 10- and 11-speed GRX cranksets [FC-RX600-10](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/grx-10-speed/FC-RX600-10.html) and [FC-RX600-11](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/component/grx-11-speed/FC-RX600-11.html)?

Net search gives "closer chainring spacing", but I'm looking for a proof.

Also interested in how the corresponding chaingings - [WP-Y0K798010](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/service-upgradeparts/grx-10-speed/WP-Y0K798010.html) and
[WP-Y0K698010](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/service-upgradeparts/grx-10-speed/WP-Y0K698010.html) - differ; similarly, looking only for verified (e.g. by measurements or technical info from the vendor) claims. Confusingly (or "ironically"), the latter page linked from the Shimano page for the 11-speed crank is under path `.../grx-10-speed/...` and says `Compatible series: GRX 10-speed`.

Comment: FWIW, Shimano's documentation says that both versions use the same inner ring, but a different outer ring. See part #s 11, 12, and 14. https://dassets.shimano.com/content/dam/global/cg1SHICCycling/final/ev/ev/EV-FC-RX600-4579A.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official technical documents available for the FC-RX600 are the [exploded view](https://si.shimano.com/en/pdfs/ev/FC-RX600-4579/EV-FC-RX600-4579B.pdf) and the [specifications sheet](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/spec/Gravel/Crankset?fst=1&q=FC-RX600&header=false&matchmodel=1).

From the exploded view, we see that:

1. The small chainring has the same part number.
2. The large chainring has a diffrent part number (might be only the color).
3. The inner chainring screw has a different part number. The RX600-10 uses a specific *inner* chainring screw, while the RX600-11 uses the same chainring screw everywhere.

The exploded view does not specifically mention that the the large chainring for one is a replacement part for the other.

On the specifications sheet, we can see the following differences:

1. RX600-11 is compatible with the LINKGLIDE and HG 11-speed chain while the RX600-10 is compatible with the HG 10-speed.
2. RX600-11 weight is 817g while RX600-10 is  821g. Not much of a difference, but this confirms they are not 1 for 1 identical.

When comparing the pictures of the front view of both cranksets on their product page, they seem pixel for pixel identical except for the color of the inner part of the large chainring.

From all of the information above, I think what is the most relevant is the chain compatibility. This would be a cue from an official source that the chainrings are indeed closer on the RX600-11 since the 11-speed chain is narrower than the 10-speed.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the difference between the screws mentioned is only in color. Y1LV98060 are silver, Y1WD98050 are black. I counted the threads and they seem to be exactly same length. The spec also says they both are 8.5mm.

I visually compared the chainrings and the ramps and pins seem identical between the two. In the past, I compared 8-speed cranksets to 10-speed there is no difference in distance between chainrings, I believe the same will apply here.

I think there might be marginal difference in the clearance between the chainrings (11-speed will have slightly less space between the rings to prevent the narrower 11-speed chain from jamming).

Generally I wouldn't loss sleep. If 2x11 is in stock and 2x10 isn't - I wouldn't hesitate to take 2x11 even if I had 10 speed drivetrain. Same the other way round.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  The question was about 10-speed versus 11-speed GRX cranksets; you appear to be responding to the other answer instead of the question. When you earn some reputation you'll be able to leave comments, in the meantime you might want to take the [tour].